# ignore null values when serializing json with jackson mixin

Tags: json, jackson

When serializing object into JSON, I need to ignore null values. Since I 
don't have access to the object source, I use Mixin classes for both 
`ObjectMapper` and `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` inside my `SpringBootApplicaiton` class:

```
public void onApplicationEvent(ObjectMapperConfigured event) {
    ObjectMapper om = event.getObjectMapper();
    om.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
    ....................................................
    om.addMixInAnnotations(target_class_I_dont_have_access_to.class, my_mixin_class.class);
    .........................................


public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {
   Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder omb = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
   omb.serializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
   ...................................................
   omb.mixIn(target_class_I_dont_have_access_to.class, my_mixin_class.class);
   .......................................................................
```

This has no effect on the JSON output.

I've also tried annotating Mixin class with `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)`, but that didn't work either.

Is there a way to get this working? Any help is appreciated!

Roman